# Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters while insert with own generated id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cryptojs

Previously in the same collection, I have been using Mongodb's own generated id as a document's `_id`. However now due to some requirements, new data needs to have a predetermined _id, which will be generated from the hash of the data to be inserted.

So I generated the hash of the data using `crypto` as below

```
var saveId = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(saveIdContents).digest('hex');
var saveIdMongo = new mongoose.mongo.ObjectID(saveId);
```

but then it will return the error

`Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters` at the line above. So is there anyway I can make `crypto` returns a string of 12 bytes or 24 hex characters?

Answer (score 1):

ObjectID is a very specific data type, see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/#objectid

A valid ObjectID value is exactly 12 bytes.

MongoDB does not impose any restriction on the type of data that my be used for the `_id` field, so if you want to use a hash instead of an ObjectID, that is completely acceptable.

In other words, don't cast `saveId` to an ObjectId, just use that value directly.

Comment: I did `var newPositiveSent = new Submission(); newPositiveSent._id = saveId;` and got this error instead `ValidationError: Submission validation failed: _id: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "6508883e94cbfc3ad52a08149642239f" at path "_id"`

Comment: Oh ya and in my schema, I didn't specify anything about `_id`

Comment: That would be the problem, if you don't specify a type for _id, most schemas will default it to ObjectID.

Comment: Ok understood. But I was reluctant to specify anything in the schema, since there's already tons of previous data inside the collection that uses MongoDB own generated id. Specifying anything about `_id` now won't cause a problem with the data inside that?